# Execute SSIS package from .NET (using SSISDB catalog) as a specific user

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package that contains a single Data Flow task.  This reads data from a csv file and dumps it in a database table.  I have deployed it to the SSISDB catalog and am running from .NET:

```
      string targetServerName = "MyServerName";
      string folderName = "TestFolder";
      string projectName = "TestProject";
      string packageName = "TestPackage";

      string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=" + targetServerName + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
      using (var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
      {
        //Set up connection to package
        IntegrationServices integrationServices1 = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection1);
        Catalog catalog = integrationServices1.Catalogs["SSISDB"];
        CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders[folderName];
        ProjectInfo project = folder.Projects[projectName];
        PackageInfo package = project.Packages[packageName];

        //Set up parameters
        Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet> executionParameters = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();
        executionParameters.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 50, ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED", ParameterValue = 1 });
        executionParameters.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 50, ParameterName = "LOGGING_LEVEL", ParameterValue = 3 });

        // Run the package
        long executionID = package.Execute(false, null, executionParameters);
      }
```

This works fine if the source csv file is stored locally on the SQL Server.  However, if the source csv file is in a network location, I get a "Cannot open the datafile" error (presumably because the user that Integration Services executes the package as doesn't have privileges to the network location).

Is it possible to execute the SSIS package **using the .NET code above**, specifying a particular Windows user that has the necessary privileges to access the network location?

*(I know that I can set it up a SQL Agent job and use a proxy account, but want to go down the .NET route as I am upgrading an existing project from SQL Server 2008 to 2016).*

Comment: Where is your code ? In a winform app ? service ? Il you execute manually the package, can it open the network csv ?

Comment: Might be a solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/impersonating-and-reverting

Comment: _Where is your code ?_ Console app.  _Il you execute manually the package, can it open the network csv ?_ – No, if I right-click on the deployed package on the server and click Execute, it comes up with the same error.  I can successfully open the source file manually

Comment: On the server, if  you execute via dtexecUI the package you have the error. On the  server if you open a windows explorer you can open the csv file... Have you check the server's windows security ? Something arround it.

Comment: Your first two statements are correct, yes.  Please could you suggest what I should check regarding the server's Windows security?